# how to accelerate intel on board graphics card?

Tags: intel-graphics

On ubuntu 13.10 saucy clean installation with an intel on-board graphics card, glxgears that comes with `mesa-utils` shows 60fps.

A much older computer with ATI card and fglrx drivers shows 600fps.

This is what lspci says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
vainfo
```

shows

```
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.33 (libva 1.1.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver - 1.0.20
```

Are there any concrete steps I can take to ensure that my intel on board card runs faster?

I went to this address https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads but the drivers are for ubuntu 13.04 and software center says dependencies are not met.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

60 fps sounds like the monitor refresh rate.  Before you decide that you're not getting hardware acceleration, try this:

```
vblank_mode=0 glxgears
```

...you might be pleasantly surprised by the results.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196117/disable-vertical-sync-for-glxgears.

Comment: since last year I realized that having higher frames per second than the monitor refresh rate on an LCD screen does nothing but waste energy. (sorry, forgot to say it was a laptop) The card already worked as it was supposed to. 

That said, I will still accept the answer to this outdated question as correct.